# Elasticsearch daterange using two date fields

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, lucene, search-engine

I send a query from the client for docs where the `currentDate` is between two values attached to all docs. The docs have an `expireDate` and an `availableDate`.

How do I formulate this query? As a guess I came up with the following, which doesn't work:

```
{
  "constant_score": {
    "filter": {
      "range" : {
        "expiredate" : {
          "lte": "2015-08-15T11:28:45.114-07:00"
        },
        "availabledate" : {
          "gte": "2015-08-11T11:28:45.114-07:00"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This even looks wrong because afaik the range won't work on a compound object or an array of one-sided ranges. I guess I could add an entire new filter so one for each field. Is there a way to use one date range for two fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of expressing that query is using two `range` filters (one for each date field) and place them in another `bool/must` filter.

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "expireDate": {
                  "lte": "2015-08-15T11:28:45.114-07:00"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "availabledate": {
                  "gte": "2015-08-11T11:28:45.114-07:00"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```